# ThreadPoolExecutor multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I created a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and tried to run multiple tasks with multiple threads. Below is a small portion of my code:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
              new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(50), threadFactory, rejectionHandler);

// prepare for threading

ArrayList<em1dFwdJava> list4 = new ArrayList<em1dFwdJava>();

// add stuff to list4

for (int i = 0; i < list4.size(); i++) {
        em1dFwdJava mytest = list4.get(i);  
        executorPool.execute(mytest);
}
```

My class `em1dFwdJava` does complex calculations that get printed to the console in the end. However, my calculations are different and wrong every time I execute them. If I were to add a `Thread.sleep(10)` at the end, the calculations would all be correct and printed in the right order. However, that would defeat the purpose since my point was to have multiple threads run this together in order to save time. Adding `Thread.sleep(10)` will only have one thread run my entire code. Is there any way for me to run my code with multiple threads while ensuring that my calculations are correct? I get this feeling that my calculations are wrong because of multithread conflicts.

Comment: Maybe lack of synchronizing?

Comment: I could be wrong, but you may need to use `ThreadPoolExecutor#submit()` rather than `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute()`.

Comment: Do you have shared fields in `em1dFwdJava`?  If so then they need to be thread-safe, e.g. immutable, synchronized, atomic, or volatile

Comment: I do use native libraries in my em1dFwdJava. Do they count as shared fields? If so, then I will try to make some changes.

Comment: If you're running into problems then these native libraries are probably sharing some resources (memory/files/whatever).  Try to have each thread spin off its own isolated copy of the native library.

Comment: Zim-Zam: Sorry I'm a bit new to this, but what do you mean by having each thread spin off its own isolated native library copy?